# c# easy way to index a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, indexing

I`m newbie at c# programming and i have one problem:
I want to add index numbers at beginning of line,sample:

```
1. m.vardas  m.pavarde  m.adresas  m.telnum  m.uzrasai
```

I think there must be better way than read file and count all lines to get number of lines in file.Here`s my code:

```
    class Mokiniai // students
    {
        struct Mokinys // student
        {
            public string vardas; // name
            public string pavarde; //last name
            public string adresas; //address
            public string telnum; //phone number
            public string uzrasai; //notes
        };
        //.........................................................
        public static void mokirasymas()
        {
            Mokinys m;
            //...................................................
            Console.WriteLine("Iveskite Mokinio varda: "); // input student name
            m.vardas = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Iveskite Mokinio pavarde: "); // input student lastname
            m.pavarde = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Iveskite Mokinio adresa: "); // input address
            m.adresas = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Iveskite Mokinio telefono numeri: "); //input number
            m.telnum = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Iveskite pastabas apie Mokini: "); //input notes
            m.uzrasai = Console.ReadLine();
            string mokinys = String.Format("|{0,15}|{1,15}|{2,15}|{3,15}|{4,15}|", m.vardas, m.pavarde, m.adresas, m.telnum, m.uzrasai);
 using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("text.txt"))
            {
                //
                // Only first time  when program is used
                //
                //writer.WriteLine("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                //writer.WriteLine("|    Vardas     |    Pavarde    |    Adresas    |  Tel.Numeris  |    Pastabos   |");
                //writer.WriteLine("|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
                //
                // 
                //
                writer.Write(mokinys);
                //
                // Iraso nauja eilute i faila
                //
                writer.Write(writer.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even though it isn't required for solving your problem, it can be helpful if you translate your variables/comments/strings to English before posting. Just a thought. --Edit: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I translated each variable to english in //................

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There may be a better way than reading the whole file to count the lines (reading the last line? Can you trust it?) There is no special file property for how many lines in the file.

If you want to know the number of lines you use [`File.ReadLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx).

Note this about ReadLines vs ReadAllLines:

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Here is an example:

```
var numLines = File.ReadLines(@"text.txt").Count();
```

Then you just add that to your format string.

Comment: In this case, there wouldn't be a difference between `File.ReadLines(fileName).Count()` and `File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Count()`, right?

Comment: I believe you are correct, but I didn't know enough to be sure. So I just included that information.